# Why is metro WebView not loading LAN IP?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webview, microsoft-metro

I'm absolutely frustrated... I'm trying to build some simple WebWrapper for the Denon page of our HIFI-system.
The problem is that the Metro WebView will not load the LAN ip address. If I change the address to e.g. "http://www.google.com" it works.
There are no error thrown and it seems to get everything right. This is what my button click should load. I also tried to set the URI directly in the Source property but still didn't work.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri hostUri = new Uri("http://192.168.0.10");
        Uri relativeUri = new Uri("MainZone/index.html", UriKind.Relative);
        Uri fullUri = new Uri(hostUri, relativeUri);
        this.webView1.Navigate(fullUri);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you enable the "Private Networks (Client & Server)" privilege in the package manifest?